# How to zoom in and zoom out image of device context(CDC) in SDI or MDI application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, zooming

I want to know how use pointer of CDC.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly, there are two ways:
- use the CDC::SetViewportOrg/SetViewportExt apis to have GDI do the scaling for you
- manually keep track of the scroll position and zoom level, and in your OnPaint, do your BitBlt or siblings to and from the correct coordinates in the source and destination DC's.

Unfortunately, most of this answer won't mean much to you without some background in MFC, which I presume you don't have from the generic nature of your question. It's a bit of a chicken and egg problem. I suggest you first read the documentation on the mentioned members of CDC (including studying the code of the example that is linked to from the MSDN docs on them), and then coming back to ask more specific questions if you can't figure it out.